# Elements of prime power order in finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N\triangleleft G$，assume that $xN$ is an element of prime power order in $G/N$. Then in the coset $xN$, does there exist an element of prime power order?

Comment: Do you require the prime power for the element in $xN$ to be at least as big as the prime power for the coset $xN$? If not the question is trivial: we can just take the identity in $G$, which has prime power order for any prime. With this restriction the answer is still yes, but the question is really too basic for MathOverflow: if $xN$ has order $p^a$ then $x$ has order divisible by $p^a$ (since $x^d = 1$ implies $(xN)^d = 1$). So $x$ has order $mp^a$ for some $m$ and then $x^m$ has order $p^a$.

Comment: @MarkWildon $x^m$ does not generally lie in $xN$.

Comment: @MarkWildon the power $x^m$ need not be in $xN$.  Concerning your initial "trivial" answer, the identity in $G$ will not be in $xN$ when $x \not\in N$.

Comment: The property you ask about is true when $G$ is a finite *abelian* group (with $xN$ containing an element whose order in $G$ equals the order of $xN$ in $G/N$) and that is one step in a proof that finite abelian groups are direct products of cyclic groups. See Chapter II, Lemma 7.3 in Lang, *Undergraduate Algebra* 2nd edition (p. 68).

Comment: The answer is yes, but this is not a research level question, and so it is not suitable for MathOveflow. It is suitable for Math.Stackexchange, but if you asked it there, in its present form then it would probably be closed for "lack of context", because you have not shown any evidence of having thought about the problem yourself.

Comment: Following Derek Holt's pointing out that the answer is yes, it may help you to note that $x$ is uniquely expressible in the form $x = yz = zy,$ where $y$ is a $p$-element and $z$  is a $p^{\prime}$-element of $C_{G}(y)$, where the order of $xN$ is a power of the prime $p$.

Comment: Sorry, indeed my answer is wrong because I forgot the key requirement. Geoff Robinson's answer shows how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. More precisely: if $p$ is a prime, and the order of $xN$ in $G/N$ is a $p$-power, then $xN$ contains an element whose order is a $p$-power. Indeed, assume that $x^{p^k}\in N$ and $x^m=1$, where $k$ and $m$ are positive integers. Write $m$ as $p^\ell n$, where $p\nmid n$. As $n$ and $p^k$ are coprime, there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that $nu-p^kv=1$. Then the element $x^{nu}=x^{1+p^kv}\in xN$ has order dividing $p^\ell$, and we are done.

Comment: Let $p^k$ be the order of $xN$ in $G/N$ (a stronger constraint than choosing $k$ so that $x^{p^k} \in N$), which implies $k \leq \ell$.  Then use relative primality of $n$ and $p^\ell$ instead of $n$ and $p^k$ at the end to write $1 = nu - p^\ell{v} = 1$ (new meaning for $u$ and $v$), so $x = x^{nu}x^{-p^\ell{v}}$. Thus $x = yz$ where $y:= x^{nu}$ has order dividing $p^\ell$ and $z := x^{-p^{\ell}v}$ is in $N$ (since $k \leq \ell$) with order dividing $n$ (so $z$ has order relatively prime to $p$) and $yz = zy$. That realizes the decomposition mentioned in Geoff's comment above.

Comment: Note the element inside $xN$ with $p$-power order need not have the same order as $xN$ does. For example, if $G = Q_8$ and $N = \{\pm 1\}$, then $G/N$ is a group of order $4$ where each nontrivial element has order $2$, but the coset representatives in $G$ of all nontrivial elements of $G/N$ belong to $\{\pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$, which all have order $4$.

Comment: @KConrad: Thanks for your comments! I thought the question was cute, and I just wanted to share quickly the answer I found while taking a shower. I agree it is not of research level, but the OP said she was studying finite group theory, so I thought the question was legitimate as well. Finite groups are fun.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: A more general fact is that if $\pi$ is the set of prime divisors of the order of $xN$, then we may choose the coset representative $x$ so that the order of $x$ has exactly the same set of prime divisors $\pi$. As in my comment this uses the fact that $x$ may be written uniquely as a product of a $\pi$-element and a $\pi^{\prime}$-element which commute ( we require $G$ finite).